# parallel an executable which has to read an input file with a fixed name in the current directory?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, exe

i have a matlab function that performs 1 MCMC chain (a sequential metropolis hastings’ for a bayesian model. at some point in the code an executable is called to simulate and then this executable saves an output file.
I tried to parallelize 2 chains however  i get the error :
forrtl: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
it is normal however i don't know how to fix it.
There is another question that asks this however they don't show the final code.

```
parfor k=1:2
result{k}=calibration(input)   
end
```

Comment: Load the file into memory before your loop if it's the same file...

Comment: yes but for example all executable write an result file that is used in the later steps of the code. I was advised to copy the file the number the chains i need to run my MCMC and  then execute each . I am used to working with python so i know the code however i am stuck doing this in Matlab

Comment: The different instances doing the parallel computation can't write to the *same* file concurrently though, they'll have to write to different files.